# vscode open CMD with the key binding CTRL + SHIFT + C

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I know there are bunch of questions for this one, but none is working for me.

Until yesterday, pressing CTRL+SHIFT+C used to open CMD at the project level folder, but nothing happens since this morning.

I guess something in VScode keybinding settings has been changed accidently, so I tried to use various `When` expressions but still no luck.

My vscode keybinding settings look like the following.

Could anyone let me know what is wrong with it please ?

[image: VSCode settings]

```html
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "editorFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  }
]
```

Comment: Is the CMD window not opening for you, or is it opening but not in the expected path?

Comment: Also, if you could include your `keybindings.json` file in your post, it may help.

Comment: @TimothyG. thanks for reaching out, It does not open the CMD window at all

Comment: @TimothyG. I have added my `keybindings.json` file

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the `when`s are conflicting somehow.  I would right click on the keybinding in the list and select Reset Keybinding.  This will reset it to its default.  Then try again and see if it opens.  The default when is `!terminalFocus`

Comment: Someone else asked a few hours ago the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67982219/vs-code-no-open-external-terminal) and now its looking like a bug with 1.57 release of VS Code, as users on GitHub are also reporting it.  It no longer works for me now too after upgrading to 1.57.

Comment: @TimothyG. Oh yes, I upgraded my vscode version to 1.57 yesterday !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue on `vscode 1.57` for about a week, but it is working now with the latest version.

Good Job `VSCODE`!