# Open External Terminal keybinding not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't open a new external terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Did a new update remove this function? I was able to use this shortcut before, but now I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the current version of Visual Studio Code, as multiple users are reporting it isn't working across different operating systems:

- [GitHub Issue #1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126115)
- [GitHub Issue #2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126331)

I updated to 1.57 the other day, and it is not working for me now either.  Previously it was on a slightly older version that I updated from.

**Update:**

The latest Visual Studio Code Insiders release (1.58) has addressed this as noted in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125985).  If you really want this functionality back, you can download the [Insiders edition](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), otherwise you'll need to wait until the next update for the main application.

**Final Update:**

The [May Recovery update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22May+2021+Recovery%22+is%3Aclosed) resolved this issue.  Download the update, and you should be able to once again open external terminals through the command.

Comment: Same thing happens for me after upgrading the vscode to v1.5.7

Comment: @AndriiNaidenko a fix has been made, but its currently only in the Insiders version of VS Code.  The next update to the main application should contain the fix.

Comment: According to that issue it is slated for a recovery update, so shouldn't be too long.

Comment: @TimothyG. They should get back soon !

Comment: @TimothyG. FYI. It got back which is good.

Answer (score 1):

It was the issue `vscode 1.57` which lasted for about an week.

If you upgrade to the latest version of vscode, it will work now.

Good Job `VSCODE` !